# JSONModel: can't assign fetched JSON to model

Tags: objective-c, jsonmodel

My JSON I fetch:

```
{"username":"example","confirmed_rewards":"5","round_estimate":"0.73605946","total_hashrate":"0","payout_history":"10","round_shares":"85",

"workers":{
"worker.1":{"alive":"0","hashrate":"0"},
"worker.2":{"alive":"0","hashrate":"0"}
}
}
```

My model:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"


@protocol LKCoinFCPoolModel @end

@interface LKCoinFCPoolModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* username;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* confirmed_rewards;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* round_estimate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* total_hashrate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* payout_history;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* round_shares;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> * ErrorCode;

@end
```

I  created the following function which is to fetch a JSON structure and assign it to a model.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    //show loader view
    [HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Fetching JSON"];

    //fetch the feed
    LKCoinFCPoolModel* test;
    test = [[LKCoinFCPoolModel alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://example.com/ap/key"

                            completion:^(LKCoinFCPoolModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {

                                                                           //hide the loader view
                                                                           [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];

                                                                           //json fetched
                                                                           NSLog(@"user: %@", test.username);

                                                                       }];}
```

the problem I'm having is that instead of `user: example` it prints `user: (null)`.

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, it's the first app I'm trying to write in xcode (I'm coming from a Python/Java background).

Comment: are you printing user, or username?

Comment: user: is just a string (for formatting), username is the variable I want to have printed

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you want  `NSLog(@"user: %@", model.username);`  or maybe even  `NSLog(@"user: %@", [model username]);`

Comment: @portforwardpodcast - It would seem so.  `test` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: DOH, of course >,< it's getting too late. Thanks guys!

Comment: @portforwardpodcast how can I assign the test variable to the model variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is passing the the parsed JSON to you in the LKCoinFCPoolModel *model.  In fact I don't think that you can assign test the way you do.  If you really wanted to get it into the test model, you should assign it inside the block.  Remember that this block runs asynchronous after the JSON is downloaded and parsed.  So test won't be valid until then.